# AJAX response to Iframe

Tags: ajax, iframe

I was wondering is it possible to fetch the ajax response and display it in a dynamic iframe as the iframe content..?

This is the part of the code :

```
$('.ifrm').html('response')

<iframe class='ifrm' src="abcd.php"></iframe>

It would be a great help if anyone tells me how to do it.. Thanks!
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have some source code you can show us?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? What were the results? Did you get any error message in the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('iframe#myFrame').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find('div.myClass').append("Hallo, Welt!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call this on button click with proper URL:

```
$(docIFrameId).empty().attr('src', <urlHere>, function () {
    // ...
});
```

*Note: Replace the `<urlHere>` part with the proper URL*